# How to use JedisPool in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, redis, jmeter, jedis

I want to loadtest redis with jmeter. I already have a working JSR223Sampler with a groovy-script

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

String varuser = "user:" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 500);

Jedis jedis = new Jedis(IP, port);
String result = jedis.hgetAll(varuser);
SampleResult.setResponseData(result.toString().getBytes());
```

under a ThreadGroup with 10 'users'. Works fine. Now I want to raise the number of 'users' to 1000. Performance will be influenced negatively by the high number of connections, right? So I want to get the advantages of a connection pool. According to

https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started

JedisPool is the answer. My question is how my jmeter testplan have to look like? Where do I have to put the jmeter-element (which one?) in which JedisPool will be created? Not under my ThreadGroup, right? And how I can use the connections from the pool in my sampler-script from above?

**EDIT**

So with Dmitris advise I createt two different testplans. Both not working. Maybe somebody sees my mistake?

First plan:

TestPlan

|---setUp Thread Group

----|---JSR223 Sampler (1)

|---Thread Group

----|---JSR223 Sampler (2)

|---View Results Tree

with JSR223 Sampler (1)

```
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), IP);
prop.put('pool', pool);
```

and JSR223 Sampler (2)

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

String varuser = "user:" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 500);

Jedis jedis = props.get('pool');
String result = jedis.hgetAll(varuser);
SampleResult. ...
jedis.close();
```

My second TestPlan looks like

TestPlan

|---ThreadGroup

----|---Test Action

--------|---JSR223 PreProcessor

----|---JSR223 Sampler

----|---View Results Tree

with PreProcessor like the above JSR223 Sampler (1) and JSR223 Sampler like the above JSR223 Sampler (2).

First Plan comes with the response message

```
cannot cast object 'redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@642715fb' with class
'redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool' to class 'redis.clients.jedis.Jedis'
```

Second Plan responds

```
no such property: pool for class: Script41082
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating JedisPool somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) using either [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (if you want to measure pool creation time) or [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler and [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) combination (if you don't want to include pool creation request into your test results)

Once done you can put this "pool" into JMeter Properties like:

1. In setUp Thread Group

   ```
   def pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), 'localhost')
   props.put('pool', pool)
   ```
2. Somewhere in the middle of your test

   ```
   def pool = props.get('pool')
   ```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: Thank you very much! Like (1) TestPlan (2) TestAction (3) JSR223 PrePro creating pool (2) JSR223 PrePro using connections (2) some Listeners ?

Comment: I edited my question... I would be delighted if you can review it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `JedisPool` from properties and try to cast it to `Jedis` which is impossible, you need to get `Jedis` from `JedisPool.getResource()`:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
....
JedisPool pool = props.get('pool');

Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
```